# How to create a column of type tinyint(2) or tinyint(3) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, tinyint

In Ruby on Rails, the following code in a migration creates a column of type `tinyint(4)` in MySQL:

```
create_table :great_table do |t|
    t.integer :step_position, :limit => 1 #tinyint
end
```

How would I create a column of type `tinyint(2)` or `tinyint(3)`?

Comment: I'd discourage you from using `tinyint` in the first place. It's overly-specific. I would venture to guess that it's actually LESS performant than using a plain integer field, as well. It might save you a negligible amount of space per-record, but I'm not even sure that's the case. I think you'd be hard-pressed to convince me that there was a reason to ever use it.

Answer (score 24):

For tinyint(2)

```
create_table :great_table do |t|
  t.integer :step_position, :limit => 2
end
```

For tinyint(3)

```
create_table :great_table do |t|
  t.integer :step_position, :limit => 3
end
```

Comment: That does not create tinyints. A tinyint uses 1 byte for storage by definition. Here you're using 2 bytes (smallint) and 3 bytes (mediumint).
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Answer (score 12):

According to what I can see in the source code of the gem, you can't:

```
     # File activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb, line   540  
     540:       def type_to_sql(type, limit = nil, precision = nil, scale = nil)
     541:         return super unless type.to_s == 'integer'
     542: 
     543:         case limit
     544:         when 1; 'tinyint'
     545:         when 2; 'smallint'
     546:         when 3; 'mediumint'
     547:         when nil, 4, 11; 'int(11)'  # compatibility with MySQL default
     548:         when 5..8; 'bigint'
     549:         else raise(ActiveRecordError, "No integer type has byte size #{limit}")
     550:         end
     551:       end
```

[type_to_sql](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html#M001551)

Comment: Not sure this is a relevant snippet of code; what's in the superclass for this? Migrations do support a `:tinyint` type. This snippet of code is where Rails decides to ignore your `:integer` type specification and use an alternate type to represent smaller/larger integer values when both `:integer` and `:limit` are specified.

Comment: Afraid you are wrong, type_to_sql is called from add_column. You can see that in the code: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html#M001549

Comment: I think I may be wrong about there being any support for a tinyint type in the first place (other than indirectly due to an integer and limit combo). The code above is certainly applied when the type is integer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as `tinyint(4)` in MySQL in the first place. `tinyint` is a one byte signed integer. You can check all integer types in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html). You may see something like `tinyint(1)` even in the Rails [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8cd143900978902ed9bbba10b34099a3140de5c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L23), but I think it's a tautology as `tinyint` already implies one byte storage.

The Rails way to declare `TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, BIGINT` in a migration is by using `limit:` with the appropriate byte size as can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8cd143900978902ed9bbba10b34099a3140de5c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L832).

Beware that Rails will treat one-byte integers as booleans by default though, as can be seen from the above link.

Comment: Actually, the number between parentheses has nothing to do with the number of bytes used for storage. It just specifies a display width, which applications displaying this number may or may not choose to honour.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:tinyint` as the column type in a rails migration, and write `limit: 2` or `limit: 3` as written before.

Using your example:

```
create_table :great_table do |t|
    t.tinyint :step_position, :limit => 1
end
```

should work.

Comment: Hey buddy, You cannot use tinyint in migration, infect it should have integer and limit 1

Comment: @Gagan Providing `add_column :table_name, :column_name, :tinyint` doesn't raise any exception and seems to go perfectly fine through the migration. I can imagine `t.tinyint` working in the same way. It could be that this is since the newer versions though, I've tested adding a tinyint column in Ruby on Rails 5.1.